# Rsync complex number pattern matching

Tags: wordpress, rsync

I am working on migrating a large WordPress website migration and only want to migrate original images. I do not want to copy the images the WordPress creates. Using rsync, I am not seeing a way in the docs to account for the multiple variations of image sizes and exclude them. The best I have come up with is to create a rule for every possible image size scenario. Is this the best I am going to get or is there a way to DRY this out?

As an example:

```sh
rsync -avPzn -e ssh webhost:/site/www.domain.com/images . 
--exclude=**\-[0-9][0-9]x[0-9][0-9].jpg 
--exclude=**\-[0-9][0-9][0-9]x[0-9][0-9].jpg 
--exclude=**\-[0-9][0-9]x[0-9][0-9][0-9].jpg 
--exclude=**\-[0-9][0-9]x[0-9][0-9].png 
--exclude=**\-[0-9][0-9][0-9]x[0-9][0-9].png 
--exclude=**\-[0-9][0-9]x[0-9][0-9][0-9].png 
...
```

An image named `image.jpg` will have multiple copies named `image-100x100.jpg` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could instead pipe into rsync the list of files you want to copy, and use   another means to exclude the unwanted image names.  This can be as simple as using `find` with a regular expression exclusion, eg:

```
ssh webhost find /site/www.domain.com/images \
  ! -regex '.*[0-9]+x[0-9]+\.\(png\|jpg\)' | \
rsync -avPzn --files-from=- webhost:/ .
```

Note, the regex has an implied `^` and `$` and uses emacs syntax by default. You may prefer a posix version:

```
-regextype posix-extended -regex '.*[0-9]+x[0-9]+\.(png|jpg)'
```

If your `find` command does not have these options, you can use `sed` or similar to filter out the filenames.
Since the find produces full pathnames, you need to get rsync to use `/` as the base.

Comment: This worked! I only needed to edit to add quotes around the find command to make it go. Thanks